# Excel: Conditional Format not Applied

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a conditional formatting function

```
=AND($A2<TODAY(),$B2<100%)
```

which works when I test it in a separate sheet /test sheet but fails when I insert it as a conditional formatting rule to format text red.

There are no other formatting rules. I cannot determine what is different in the data /non-test sheet.

Comment: How are we supposed to determine what is different based on the information you've provided? At least post a screenshot.

Comment: Side note, but instead of `$B2<100%`, you can just use `$B2<1`.

Comment: It's almost certainly related to the Applies To: range in your conditional formatting rule. Make sure it covers the entire range you're trying to format.

Comment: @SJR Can't due to proprietary. But I can tell you number formats are also same, e.g. column A is dates, column B is percentages.

Comment: @FlexYourData I believe its applied to my whole column I want to format, e.g. $A$1:$A$100 if I had 100 rows starting 1 to 100

Comment: Set the top row of the applies to range to be the row specified in the rule definition. If your rule references A2 and B2, then the applies to range should be A2:B100 (if you want to color both columns)

Comment: @FlexYourData I assume by your comment you mean to use the top row in the rules definition, e.g. since A2 and B2 are the first entries I evaluate. FYI Formatting is applied to a separate column

Comment: Please edit your post with a screenshot of the rule definition, some test data and the appliesto range.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have setup conditional formatting correctly? Try verifying the "Applies to" range. Also are the values in date & percentage columns actual values and not text in the non test sheet? It works perfectly fine for me[image: Setup ss and proof]

Comment: Honestly Like you I have an example that works with example data. So something must be wrong with the actual data....I know the data format is consistent (i.e. dates are formatted as dates, percentages as percentages) and there are definitely cases that would trigger the conditional formatting TRUE condition. Maybe there's something else I'm not checking?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, formatting data values to a particular data format doesn't actually convert the data to that format. I'm stuck with the old data format still and that's why the code didn't interpret the values correctly.

Not sure how to resolve this issue since I really don't want to re-enter all the dates already there just in its original exported format.

Comment: Why are you posting this as an answer? You can format the date values using formulas. If the content in the cell is 01-01-2020, but it is in text, you can just use the formula =datevalue(A1)    This is assuming the date is in column A1

Comment: @Xlsx this is oversimplifying the solution. In my case I have a date string but it's nothing interpretable without making a custom formula to convert it

Comment: If it is not interpretable then MS Excel will have no way of knowing it as a date.